# Computer won't boot up

Tags: boot, crash

I stopped using my laptop for a while. Tried to get back on it to find that it had gone into sleep mode which was weird because it doesn't do that. I turned it on normally and tried to open Chrome but it won't open, I tried a couple of times, but everything froze. So I manually tried to restart the laptop. Upon re-start, all I'm seeing is a black screen with "-" dash at the top left. I can type on the screen but it doesn't go any forward from there nor does it boot up. Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Can you select a virtual terminal (ctrl+Alt+F4), and get a text login?  Maybe just a video problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to power it off, remove the battery, then press and hold the power-up button for a few seconds, then plug the battery back in and plug the machine in the mains to recharge for about one hour before trying to turn it on again.